# Expansion of what?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, time-dilation

When people say "the expansion of the Universe" they seem to mean the expansion of the space between mass-dense regions. However, my understanding is that space and time are intrinsically linked, so ① shouldn't time be "shrinking" (ticking slower) as space expands? ② Wouldn't that account for for redshift variances?

If not, please explain how/why time is unaffected by expansion.

Note: I have read [spacetime expansion and universe expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24324/), but it hasn't cleared up these questions for me.

Comment: You're trying to reason about general relativity using words rather than equations, and it isn't working very well. Your #1 doesn't follow logically from the earlier material, so the "gee whiz" stuff in #2 and #3 is unfounded.

Comment: I wasn't aware that words weren't allowed. Are you attempting to say "① No. (No follow up.) ② No. See 1. ③ No. (No follow up.) ④ I refuse to answer." Because I'm not understanding your comment other than to say "You're doing it wrong," which is discouraging. I'm not sure why this is so common among the online physics communities.

Comment: I asked my cosmology professor and he simply said, "I hope not." That was equally unsatisfying.

Comment: Don't worry Rubellite, others try to reason about Relativity using words, or even just thoughts, for example: Einstein.

Comment: @TomB. :  I think we can all agree that if the OP were to emulate Einstein's ratio of equations to words, the question could be much improved.

Comment: To say that the universe expands is to say that spatial distances are greater at one time than they are at another.   But it makes no sense to ask whether spacetime expands (or shrinks) because any expansion or shrinkage is already built into what spacetime **is**.  In other words, spacetime cannot be different today than it was yesterday, because today and yesterday were both part of spacetime all along.

Comment: @Ben Crowell, if you don't understand the question, why not ask for clarification? If, OTOH it's clear that OP is under a misapprehension, why not explain the concept?

Comment: @WillO, but I think we can also agree that if we all emulated Einstein's ratio of answers to condescensions, this site could be much improved.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I don't know what makes stack exchangers so prone to downvote and be critical without actually being helpful or, even useful. I know it has prevented me asking questions; who knows how many others.

Comment: @WillO Please differentiate "spacetime cannot be different today than it was yesterday, because today and yesterday were both part of spacetime all along," from "spacetime cannot be different here than it is there, because here and there are both part of spacetime all along," for me. IOW, if it acts on space, why not time?

Comment: I suspect that some PhSEers feel that questioners don't do enough work to answer their own questions before asking. While that is a legitimate concern, it seems often misplaced in my view. Keep asking questions.

Comment: @RubelliteFae :  It makes sense to talk about all of space at time 1, or all of space at time 2.  It makes sense to talk about all of time at the North Pole, or all of time at the South Pole.  But it makes no sense to talk about all of space at the North Pole, or all of time at time 0.  When we talk about "expansion", we are comparing conditions at two different times,  not two different places.  So it makes sense to talk about space expanding (so space is different at time 2 than at time 1) but not about time expanding.

Comment: @WillO Thanks, and I understand that, but we are also comparing expansion in region 1 vs expansion in region 2, where region 2 is more distant from the observer than region 1 is.

Comment: I'm finding more versions of this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83531/does-time-expand-with-space-or-contract || https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170406/space-is-expanding-so-what-is-time-doing  || https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376343/time-dilation-due-to-space-expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, time and space are, to some extents, "linked". I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "shrink" in this question. It *is* true that the expansion not only makes distant galaxies recede at velocities proportional to their distances, but also makes their time run at a slower pace, as observed by us.

This general relativistic time dilation is observed all the time, e.g. in supernova lightcurves which show how their brightness of supernovae decline with time after the explosion. The farther away a galaxy is, the slower it is obseved to decline.

This does not *cause* their redshift; rather, both effects are caused by the same phenomenon, namely expansion. But both effects add to diminish the flux that we receive from distant sources. The wavelength of light that we receive from a galaxy is "stretched" by a factor $(1+z)$, where $z$ is called "it's redshift" and is given by the size of the Universe when the light was emitted, relative to the size it has now. General relativity predicts, and observations confirm, that time is dilated by the *same* factor, $(1+z)$.

That is, the flux we receive is diminished by a factor $(1+z)^2$ more than the usual inverse square law predicts — one factor for the less energy per photon (due to the redshift), and one factor for the smaller number of photons emitted per time interval (due to the galaxy's time interval taking longer than our time interval).

All of this is true irrespective of the rate of the expansion; in particular whether the rate is accelerating.

Comment: This was well put together and the explanation is great for a broader audience. Thanks.

Comment: @RubelliteFae Let me know if you want a more mathematically rigorous explanation.

Comment: No, your explanation is great for my level, but it seems to conflict with other answers I've come across. Otherwise I would choose it as the answer.

Comment: @RubelliteFae Well… I don't mean to say that I'm right and they're wrong, but… if they're in conflict with this answer, they _are_ wrong. The time dilation for objects at cosmological distances is very real, and frequently observed. Trust me, I'm an astronomer :)